# dynamically create datasets in flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, flot

I want to dynamically create my dataset for a graph. now I got something like this, and it works as intended but I won't know the length of the array so i can't use this and when i try a loop inside the data object it fails. any sugestions?

```
var month=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Maj","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dec");
var day =new Array();
var mon =new Array();
var pass =new Array();
var bug =new Array();

_.each(data, function(data){          
var date = new Date(data['timestamp']);
mon.push(date.getMonth());
day.push(date.getDate());    
pass.push(data['pass']);
bug.push(data['bug']);
}); 

  var datasets = {
  "Pass": {
  label: "Pass",
  data: [[""+month[mon[0]]+"-"+day[0]+"",  pass[0]], [""+month[mon[1]]+"-"+day[1]+"",  pass[1]], [""+month[mon[2]]+"-"+day[2]+"",  pass[2]], [""+month[mon[3]]+"-"+day[3]+"",  pass[3]], [""+month[mon[4]]+"-"+day[4]+"",  pass[4]]]

  },
  "Bug": {
  label: "Bug",
  data: [[""+month[mon[0]]+"-"+day[0]+"",  bug[0]], [""+month[mon[1]]+"-"+day[1]+"",  bug[1]], [""+month[mon[2]]+"-"+day[2]+"",  bug[2]], [""+month[mon[3]]+"-"+day[3]+"",  bug[3]], [""+month[mon[4]]+"-"+day[4]+"",  bug[4]]]
  }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the data object before you build the dataset. you cannot loop inside the dataset, but you can loop outside.

or you can make an object out of your dataset, and then JSON.Stringify() it.

Edit to show how to do the second, code might not be 100% correct so adapt for your scenario:

```
var dataset= new Object();
dataset.label = "Bug";
foreach(var i in DatestoAdd){
dataset.Dates.add(DatestoAdd[i]);
}
JSON.Stringify(dataset);
```

Comment: A capital S in stringify will result in an error, it should be lowercase.